# Redis airflow timeout

Tags: python, redis, airflow, timeout

Good morning everyone, I'm trying to connect to Redis, but I'm getting a timeout error.
Airflow version: 2.4.2, Redis version: 3.5.
When I connect via a Python script, outside the context of a DAG, the connection is established. However, when I create a task to run, it doesn't work.

I've tried connecting through the command line, using the BashOperator, and I've also tested setting the Redis host and port configuration directly in the web server's connections. But nothing is resolving the issue.

I've also tried modularizing the connection files because apparently it's the DAG that's not able to establish the connection. So, I created a Python script to connect and perform set/get operations, but when I set a task to execute the Python file, it doesn't work either. However, if I run it independently, outside the context of the DAG, it connects successfully.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Which executor are you using?